# eps2pgf error: /undefined in currentlinecap

Tags: tikz-pgf, eps, postscript

I'm encountering a problem when converting .eps to .pgf with eps2pgf. I'm running OSX Yosemite with Java version 1.8.0_31.

This is what I input in Terminal:

```
java -jar eps2pgf.jar figure1.eps -o figure1.pgf
```

(to be clear: I don't think it's a path problem, because I specify the whole path in terminal, for every file. I just didn't do it here because that wouldn't be very clear for you.)

When I run the command, the following error is returned:

```
ERROR: A PostScript error occurred.
ERROR:     Type: Error: /undefined in currentlinecap
ERROR:     Operand stack (max top 10 items):
ERROR:       |- 1.3
ERROR: Execution failed due to a PostScript error in the input file.
```

The input file is a `.eps` file exported directly from SPSS output as a `.eps` file. I have no reason to believe there is anything wrong with it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this connected to `(La)TeX`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I'm trying to get my SPSS output into `LaTeX`. I don't want to include picture files in my document, because it's very frustrating and a lot of hassle to format it so that it fits in nicely with the layout of my document. The best option I found was to export `.eps` from SPSS, and then convert that to `.pgf`, so that the formatting can be done natively in `LaTeX`.